# How to fire action on date change?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sqlite, uilocalnotification

I have SQLite database.

I want to insert row in database when date changes.

I just know that i should use `UILocalNotification`,But I don't know how.

Other way is to run NSTimer in background but I don't want to do that.

From tutorial I tried:

```
UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSDate *date = [NSDate date]; 
// create the notification and then set it's parameters
UILocalNotification *notification = [[[UILocalNotification alloc] init] autorelease];
if (notification)
{
        
    notification.fireDate = date;
    notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    notification.repeatInterval = 0;
    notification.alertBody = @"DONE:";
    
    // this will schedule the notification to fire at the fire date
    [app scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
    
    // this will fire the notification right away, it will still also fire at the date we set
    [app presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
 }
```

But in my app it should insert in database either app is in background or foreground. Insertion should place when date changes.

Comment: Why do you need to add this row at the exact time the date changes? Why not simply add a new row if your app starts on a new day and the row hasn't been added yet?

Comment: NSTimer only works for 10 minutes in background, better use UILocalNotification as per your requirement.

Comment: no i want to insert when date changes.. and if i do what you are saying then also at morning 10 o'clock i have to send notification to user.. either app is in background or foreground..

Answer (score 0):

You can store [NSDate date]; to some variable and put condition according to last date and change that variable inside that condition with today's date with the use of [NSDate date]; and do modifications as you want.

Comment: i am getting date but i want to insert row in database at midnight when date changes...

Comment: ohh i see then you need to set localPushNotification for that with stored date and changed date.

Comment: and if there is a php webservice involved with your app then you can get the notification at the serverside as it's lot easier at server side to take account of date change

Comment: no my app is completely based on clock and notifications no web services involved... do you have any link so that i can refer...

Comment: you can try these 2 links 1) http://stackoverflow.com/a/16654552/2695503   and 2) http://stackoverflow.com/a/6048040/2695503

don't forgot to upvote if it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with `UILocalNotification` then see below information.

Set `fireDate` of `UILocalNotification` as you need and your notification will generated on this date.
And you will get generated notification at **2 (Two) ways.** such like,

**1)** in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

=> it is helpful if your application is not running;

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   .
   .
   .
   UILocalNotification *localNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
   if (localNotif) 
   {
      /// do your stuff
   }
   .
   .
}
```

**2)** use delegate method of `UILocalNotification`

=> it is helpful if your application is running;

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {
    /// do your stuff
}
```

You can write your insert data here;

Comment: yes i know that... but  where should i write fire notification so that notification fired based on clock without depending any clicks or background foreground of application..

Comment: when date changes... midnight 12:00 clock to insert row in database.. at 11:00 am update row in database and at 6:00 pm to update in database. hope now clear..

Comment: This is bad idea to use notification but you can do it as  create 3 notification in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions with different fireDate such like 12:00 clock, 11:00 am and 6:00 pm and i hope you know after what you need to do :)

Comment: then instead of notification what should i use?

Comment: it is not possible to fire notification as such type, if you have not opened your application about 5 days then how you can update/insert data in your database of this 5 days ??

Comment: @ChitraKhatri - I dnt know dear , :( Discuss on Here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15038/ios-developer-family

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

```
// date change
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(dateChange) name:UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification object:nil];
```

Implement method in `YourDelegate.m` file

```
-(void)dateChange
{
  if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"LastAppOpenTime"] != nil)
  {
    NSDate *lastDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"LastAppOpenTime"];
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];

    NSTimeInterval distanceBetweenDates = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:lastDate];
    double secondsInAnHour = 3600;
    NSInteger hoursBetweenDates = distanceBetweenDates / secondsInAnHour;

    if (hoursBetweenDates >= 24)
    {
        //update database here.
    }
  }

  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"LastAppOpenTime"];//Store current date
}
```